# Model filled but values nil after CSV import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

Am try trying to import a tabbed file and am using Ruby CSV. The trouble is the values added to the database are returning nil and I can't figure out why.

Here's my method:

```
require 'csv'

desc "Import GB.full from csv file"
task :import => [:environment] do

  file = "codes.csv"

  CSV.foreach(file, :col_sep => "\t") do |row|
    Place.create {
        country_code = row[0],
        postal_code = row[1],
        place_name = row[2],
        admin_name_1 = row[3],
        admin_code_1 = row[4],
        admin_name_2 = row[5],
        admin_code_2 = row[6],
        admin_name_3 = row[7],
        admin_code_3 = row[8],
        latitude = row[9],
        longitude = row[10],
        accuracy = row[11]
    }
    puts row[0]
    end

end
```

Here's a snippet of my model entry from Rails console:

```
irb(main):030:0> Place.all
  Place Load (3.8ms)  SELECT "places".* FROM "places"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Place id: 1, country_code: nil, postal_code: nil, place_name: nil, admin_name_1: nil, admin_code_1: nil, admin_name_2: nil, admin_code_2: nil, admin_name_3: nil, admin_code_3: nil, latitude: nil, longitude: nil, accuracy: nil, created_at: "2016-01-23 18:10:40", updated_at: "2016-01-23 18:10:40">, #<Place id: 2, country_code: nil, postal_code: nil, place_name: nil, admin_name_1: nil, admin_code_1: nil, admin_name_2: nil, admin_code_2: nil, admin_name_3: nil, admin_code_3: nil, latitude: nil, longitude: nil, accuracy: nil, created_at: "2016-01-23 18:10:40", updated_at: "2016-01-23 18:10:40">, #<Place id: 3, country_code: nil, postal_code: nil, place_name: nil, admin_name_1: nil, admin_code_1: nil, admin_name_2: nil, admin_code_2: nil, admin_name_3: nil, admin_code_3: nil, latitude: nil, longitude: nil, accuracy: nil, created_at: "2016-01-23 18:10:40", updated_at: "2016-01-23 18:10:40">, #<Place id: 4, country_code: nil, postal_code: nil, place_name: nil, admin_name_1: nil, admin_code_1: nil, admin_name_2: nil, admin_code_2: nil, admin_name_3: nil, admin_code_3: nil, latitude: nil, longitude: nil, accuracy: nil, created_at: "2016-01-23 18:10:40", updated_at: "2016-01-23 18:10:40">
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem in this line

```
Place.create {...}
```

This line is interpetended by Ruby as calling method `create` of class `Place` with **block**. If you want to pass the hash as an argument to method `create` it should be written as

```
Place.create({country_code: row[0]...})
```

If you want to use block syntax, then you have to pass an yielded object and setup attributes on this object like this:

```
Place.create { |place| place.country_code = row[0] ...}
```

See [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#create) for more info.